# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_globalThis.crypto.subtle.digest') react-native ios

Tags: ios, react-native

I am having this error [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_globalThis.crypto.subtle.digest')] in my app when i am using a transaction function :-

```
var fromTokenAccount = await myToken.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
      fromWallet.publicKey)
```

this function uses the **npm i react-native-crypto** ,
this is not happening when i **ON** the debug mode

Comment: There's not enough code to help you effectively. Could you add the whole error log and a bit more code specific to this error?

Comment: hello Buzz, i am using link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236211/how-to-transfer-custom-token-by-solana-web3-js" having code in the answer, but using in react-native.