# Solana spl token transfer python

Tags: python, solana, nft

I need to automatically transfer NFT from one wallet to another. I'm using python and couldn't find information anywhere on how to do this. Here is an example transaction https://solscan.io/tx/4JaLzHB44rBA74YiFV2kjDeVu79qWdvcwDiuDdwML9XtysXHchwWwMN4KuGuJph83m8JH56cgXEMMCC2u3cuxqPM . The only thing I could find is this [How to transfer custom token by '@solana/web3.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236211/how-to-transfer-custom-token-by-solana-web3-js) but I'm very far from JS. As I understand it, I need to create something like `splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction` but I could not find an analogue for python. And I also don’t understand what token they are transferring, because I don’t see the token id anywhere. If someone can help - I will be very grateful. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In python, you can use the SPL token client included in the `solana-py` repo at https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/tree/master/src/spl/token

To do the transfer, based on the example transaction that you linked, you use:

- token id / mint: `Crh6XxeJoKGVbCKaCXzD57pkUv5vYwgW3acnKWP91bWV`
- source account: `AqCV7nMqWY8TnN9VqNrdvGNcchHjkbZfjSoLXSTeE9Fb`
- destination account: `vLswbP3WbNRyE4FBaj7GdQj3hG5CKgJGw9fEGaA165z`
- source account owner / authority: `5j22en4YDzDNzmGm7WWVxxYGDQ3Y873p7joVbKncZ1Ke`
- amount: 1

This gives you:

```py
from spl.token.constants import TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
from spl.token.instructions import transfer_checked, TransferCheckedParams

from solana.rpc.commitment import Confirmed
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.rpc.types import TxOpts
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.transaction import Transaction

transaction = Transaction()
transaction.add(
    transfer_checked(
        TransferCheckedParams(
    program_id=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    source=new PublicKey("AqCV7nMqWY8TnN9VqNrdvGNcchHjkbZfjSoLXSTeE9Fb"),
    mint=new PublicKey("Crh6XxeJoKGVbCKaCXzD57pkUv5vYwgW3acnKWP91bWV"),
    dest=new PublicKey("vLswbP3WbNRyE4FBaj7GdQj3hG5CKgJGw9fEGaA165z"),
    owner=new PublicKey("5j22en4YDzDNzmGm7WWVxxYGDQ3Y873p7joVbKncZ1Ke"),
    amount=1,
    decimals=0,
    signers=[]
        )
    )
)
client = Client(endpoint="https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com", commitment=Confirmed)
owner = Keypair() # <-- need the keypair for the token owner here! 5j22en4YDzDNzmGm7WWVxxYGDQ3Y873p7joVbKncZ1Ke
client.send_transaction(
    transaction, owner, opts=TxOpts(skip_confirmation=False, preflight_commitment=Confirmed))
```

Here's an integration test using `transfer_checked`, same as the SolScan transaction that you linked: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/f41f020938d1fb257142f18608bcb884adb54479/tests/integration/test_token_client.py#L231

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30974266)

Comment: Noted, edited to add a full example

Comment: I have updated the answer, This answer is no longer valid. Its a great starting point though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72665347/solana-transaction-using-python/73264835#73264835