# Solana transaction using python

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-transaction-instruction

I am trying to make a transaction using python in the Solana network, I am using solana.py python library and anchor.py, but I am unable to identify how to open the wallet for signing the transaction

Comment: Have you seen solana cookbook? https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-sol

Comment: Yes, we can send transactions using private key, but i am unable to popup the wallet for signing the transaction by providing public key in the transaction instructions.

Comment: how are you using python in the browser, for wallet to popup you have to use a browser package like web3js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER: AUG-2022

This took me quite some time to figure out. I have only traveled part of the road. The next steps are fro you to take on your own.

What you will need:

1. A wallet address with SOL (devnet) and secret key
2. A token
3. A token account with the tokens you will send.
4. A empty token account to send tokens to

The easiest way to do this is by following tutorials on how to create and send tokens through the solana-cli and token-spl command line. (please use ubuntu lxd lxc containers so you don't have to worry about your pc) I recommend network chucks solana tutorial.

Try doing this in Shell to begin with, next do as you please.

```
from spl.token.constants import TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
from spl.token.instructions import transfer_checked, TransferCheckedParams

from solana.rpc.commitment import Confirmed
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.rpc.types import TxOpts
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.transaction import Transaction


from_token_account = PublicKey("Brnvzh...bGPED")
to_token_account = PublicKey("6Uij3...Ahmtp")
from_wallet_address = PublicKey("rjPKeL...wedQp")
mint_public_id = PublicKey("4qYnL....Pt4taGk")
SECRET_KEY = bytes([43,124,...,3,226,229,189]) #from the account you are sending from. AKA owner account. You will find this in id.json 

transaction = Transaction()
transaction.add(
    transfer_checked(
        TransferCheckedParams(
            TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, #DON'T WORRY ABOUT THIS! DON'T TOUCH IT!
            from_token_account, #Its not your wallet address! Its the token account address!
            mint_public_id, # token address 
            to_token_account, # to the receiving token account.
            from_wallet_address, # wallet address connected to the from_token_account. needs to have SOL
            1, #amount of tokens to send.
            9, #default decimal places. Don't touch in it most cases
            [] #default. Don't touch it in most cases

        )
    )
)
client = Client(endpoint="https://api.devnet.solana.com", commitment=Confirmed) #devnet you can change it to the main net if you want
owner = Keypair.from_secret_key(SECRET_KEY) # <-- need the keypair for the token owner here! [20,103,349, ... 230,239,239]
client.send_transaction(
    transaction, owner, opts=TxOpts(skip_confirmation=False, preflight_commitment=Confirmed)) #don't touch it in most cases.
```

Comment: Running it gives me this error
```
solana.rpc.core.RPCException: {'code': -32002, 'message': 'Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x4', 'data': {'accounts': None, 'err': {'InstructionError': [0, {'Custom': 4}]}, 'logs': ['Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]', 'Program log: Instruction: Transfer', 'Program log: Error: owner does not match', 'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4470 of 200000 compute units', 'Program Tokenk...A failed: custom program error: 0x4'], 'unitsConsumed': 0}}
```

Comment: It could be a lot of things. 'Program log: Error: owner does not match'. The private key you are using, does it match "from_wallet_address" You can check by `owner = Keypair.from_secret_key(SECRET_KEY).public_key' make sure they both match.