# How to transfer token using spl-token 0.1.8

Tags: javascript, typescript, solana

I have this code that transfers a token using spl-token 0.2.x.

How do I have the same code work in 0.1.8? From my understanding of the docs, there were no breaking changes between the two, but the older version uses a Token class, but I'm not sure how to call it for the `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` and `transfer` functions.

```
async function transferToken(endpoint: string, fromWallet: Keypair, address_to: string, token_id: string)
{
    const connection = new Connection(endpoint);
    const toWalletPublicKey = new PublicKey(address_to);
    const mint_key = new PublicKey(token_id);

    // From
    const from = [connection, fromWallet, mint_key, fromWallet.publicKey];
    const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(...from);

    // To
    const to = [connection, fromWallet, mint_key, toWalletPublicKey];
    const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(...to);

    // Transfer
    const transferParams = [connection, fromWallet, fromTokenAccount.address, toTokenAccount.address, fromWallet.publicKey, 1, []];
    return await transfer(...transferParams);  
}
```

This is how I pass the `fromWallet` `KeyPair` loaded from hex string.

```
const fromWallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(private_key, 'hex')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually version 2 does have break changes (hence the major bump of the version), in this case it was removing the `Token` class in favour of those functions that you see in the example.

The docs are quite... bad, but if you check [the Github project one year ago](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/02a6854f681ba9ca24cb4be96fca07f4acf4d3b2/token/js/client/token.js#L536) then you can see how the function was migrated little by little.

`getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` and `transfer` require to use the class Token in the next way:

```js
const token = new Token(connection, toWalletPublicKey, mint_key, fromWallet.publicKey) // Not sure about the last argument as it is the Signer

/**
   * Retrieve the associated account or create one if not found.
   *
   * This account may then be used as a `transfer()` or `approve()` destination
   *
   * @param owner User account that will own the new account
   * @return The new associated account
   */
const fromTokenAccount = token.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(fromWallet.publicKey)

const toTokenAccount = token.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(toWalletPublicKey)

/**
* Transfer parameters
* @param source Source account
* @param destination Destination account
* @param owner Owner of the source account
* @param multiSigners Signing accounts if `owner` is a multiSig
* @param amount Number of tokens to transfer
*/
token.transfer(fromTokenAccount, toTokenAccount, fromWallet, [], 1)
```

Also this is partially answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236211/how-to-transfer-custom-token-by-solana-web3-js/69522224#69522224)

Comment: Ok! I think I'm not creating the signer correctly. How do I do this with a private key? This is how I create the KeyPair (fromWallet) from a stored private key.

Comment: Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(private_key, 'hex')))

Comment: since you only have one signer, you can leave the signer alone in the transfer, it should come from the `fromTokenAccount` as for the initialization of the token the Signer is just the KeyPar you are pointing at. 

Do you get any particular error?

Comment: `.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/transaction.ts:611
      const key = signer.publicKey.toString();
                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')`

Comment: have you debug that the signer that you are passing contains both private and public key?

Comment: Yes, the signer contains both the private and public key when I log it out. If I pass `fromWallet` instead of `fromWallet.publicKey` I get this error. `    throw new Error('Non-base' + BASE + ' character')
          ^
Error: Non-base58 character`

Comment: I also added how I create the KeyPair from a stored hex string of the private key. My 0.2.0 code example works with these values.

Comment: Also, if I add `await` to `token.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(fromWallet.publicKey)` it gives me this error. `Error: Failed to find account`